# How to efficiently aggregate multiple data.table columns by groups, N-at-a-time, where N is variable

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

The dataset I am using is structured as follows:

```
library("data.table")

   dt <- data.table(Id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), "01.01.2005" = c(10,0,0,0,5,7,7,0),
 "02.01.2005" = c(4,5,7,0,0,0,9,9), "03.01.2005" = c(2,3,3,6,7,77,45,0), 
"04.01.2005" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), "05.01.2005" = c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,2), 
"06.01.2005" = c(45,15,45,54,5,76,67,10), "07.01.2005" = c(0,0,0,0,466,21,832,54), 
"08.01.2005" = c(2,3,734,2,3,4,5,6))

>dt
       Id 01.01.2005 02.01.2005 03.01.2005 04.01.2005 05.01.2005 06.01.2005 07.01.2005 08.01.2005
    1:  1         10          4          2          0          0         45          0          2
    2:  2          0          5          3          0          1         15          0          3
    3:  3          0          7          3          0          1         45          0        734
    4:  4          0          0          6          0          1         54          0          2
    5:  5          5          0          7          0          1          5        466          3
    6:  6          7          0         77          0          0         76         21          4
    7:  7          7          9         45          0          0         67        832          5
    8:  8          0          9          0          1          2         10         54          6
```

I need to sum the an amount of columns by a a certain step. I.e. if the step = 2 then column (2,3) are aggregated, (4,5), (6,7), and (8,9) as well. The output needs to look as follows:

```
>output
       Id 01.01.2005-02.01.2005 03.01.2005-04.01.2005 05.01.2005-06.01.2005 07.01.2005-08.01.2005
    1:  1                    14                     2                    45                     2
    2:  2                     5                     3                    16                     3
    3:  3                     7                     3                    46                   734
    4:  4                     0                     6                    55                     2
    5:  5                     5                     7                     6                   469
    6:  6                     7                    77                    76                    25
    7:  7                    16                    45                    67                   837
    8:  8                     9                     1                    12                    60
```

To achieve this I am using a loop:

```
output <- dt[, list(Id)]
step = 2
for(i in seq(nrow(dt), 2, by = -step)){
     output <- cbind(output, temp.col = rowSums(dt[, i:(i-step+1), with = F], 
                      na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1))
     setnames(output, "temp.col", "new.name...")
}
```

but for large datasets this approach is very slow. Is there a function that exists that does what I need without a loop?

Furthermore: "step" needs to be a variable input.

thanks in advance

Comment: Title should be *"How to efficiently aggregate multiple data.table columns by groups, N-at-a-time, where N is variable"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another possible approach

```
step <- 2
temp <- melt(dt, "Id")[, indx := rep(seq_len((ncol(dt)-1L)/step), each = nrow(dt)*step)]
dcast(temp, Id ~ indx, sum, value.var = "value")
#    Id  1  2  3   4
# 1:  1 14  2 45   2
# 2:  2  5  3 16   3
# 3:  3  7  3 46 734
# 4:  4  0  6 55   2
# 5:  5  5  7  6 469
# 6:  6  7 77 76  25
# 7:  7 16 45 67 837
# 8:  8  9  1 12  60
```

Comment: Yes, this. data.table is designed for long-format data, which would be more sensible for OP's data anyway.

Comment: @Roland would you suggest leaving the data in long-format, making the changes (i.e. aggregating rows), and then converting to wide?

Comment: with `step <-3`, this gives a different result using the original dataset. May be something like `temp <- melt(dt, "Id")[, {tmp <- rep(seq_len((ncol(dt)-1L)/step), each = nrow(dt)*step); cbind(indx=tmp,.SD[seq(tmp)])}]`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
f1 <- function(DT, step){
  m1 <- as.matrix(DT[,-1])
  lst <- lapply(seq(step), function(i) seq(i, ncol(m1), by = step))
  nm1 <- do.call(paste, c(lapply(lst, function(x) colnames(m1)[x]), sep="_"))
  res <- cbind(Id= DT[["Id"]], as.data.table(Reduce(`+`,
                                 lapply(lst, function(i) m1[,i]))))
  setnames(res, 2:ncol(res), nm1)
  res}

f1(dt, 2)  
#   Id 01.01.2005_02.01.2005 03.01.2005_04.01.2005 05.01.2005_06.01.2005
#1:  1                    14                     2                    45
#2:  2                     5                     3                    16
#3:  3                     7                     3                    46
#4:  4                     0                     6                    55
#5:  5                     5                     7                     6
#6:  6                     7                    77                    76
#7:  7                    16                    45                    67
#8:  8                     9                     1                    12
#   07.01.2005_08.01.2005
#1:                     2
#2:                     3
#3:                   734
#4:                     2
#5:                   469
#6:                    25
#7:                   837
#8:                    60
```

Testing with other "step"

```
dt1 <- data.table(Id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
"01.01.2005" =   c(10,0,0,0,5,7,7,0),
"02.01.2005" = c(4,5,7,0,0,0,9,9), "03.01.2005" = c(2,3,3,6,7,77,45,0), 
"04.01.2005" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), "05.01.2005" = c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,2), 
"06.01.2005" = c(45,15,45,54,5,76,67,10),
"07.01.2005" = c(0,0,0,0,466,21,832,54), 
"08.01.2005" = c(2,3,734,2,3,4,5,6),
"09.01.2005"= c(4, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11))

f1(dt1, 3)
# Id 01.01.2005_02.01.2005_03.01.2005 04.01.2005_05.01.2005_06.01.2005
#1:  1                               16                               45
#2:  2                                8                               16
#3:  3                               10                               46
#4:  4                                6                               55
#5:  5                               12                                6
#6:  6                               84                               76
#7:  7                               61                               67
#8:  8                                9                               13
#   07.01.2005_08.01.2005_09.01.2005
#1:                                6
#2:                                6
#3:                              737
#4:                                7
#5:                              476
#6:                               34
#7:                              847
#8:                               71
```

#### Update

Another option would be using `set` from `data.table`.  The new function `f2` will not depend on the number of columns in the dataset.  `f1` will fail on 'dt' if the `step <- 3`.  With `f2`, if the number of columns to be used for computation is '8' with step as '3', it gets the `rowSums` of 1st 3, `rowSums` of 4:6, and `rowSums` of 7:8.  In the example, it was not clear how the OP want to `sum` in those cases.  Similarly for `step <- 5`, we get the the `rowSums` of 1st 5 columns, then `6:8`

```
f2 <- function(DT, step){
  indx <- 2:ncol(DT)
  indx1 <-  (seq_along(indx)-1)%/%step +1L
  lst <- split(indx, indx1)
  nm1 <- sapply(lst, function(i) paste(names(DT)[i], collapse="_")) 
  res <- as.data.table(matrix(0, ncol=length(lst),
               nrow=nrow(dt), dimnames=list(NULL, nm1)))

  for(j in seq_along(res)){
   set(res, i=NULL, j=j, value=DT[, lst[[j]], with=FALSE][, Reduce(`+`, .SD)])
   }
  cbind(Id=DT[['Id']], res)
  } 

f2(dt,2)
#   Id 01.01.2005_02.01.2005 03.01.2005_04.01.2005 05.01.2005_06.01.2005
#1:  1                    14                     2                    45
#2:  2                     5                     3                    16
#3:  3                     7                     3                    46
#4:  4                     0                     6                    55
#5:  5                     5                     7                     6
#6:  6                     7                    77                    76
#7:  7                    16                    45                    67
#8:  8                     9                     1                    12
#   07.01.2005_08.01.2005
#1:                     2
#2:                     3
#3:                   734
#4:                     2
#5:                   469
#6:                    25
#7:                   837
#8:                    60

f2(dt,3)
# Id 01.01.2005_02.01.2005_03.01.2005 04.01.2005_05.01.2005_06.01.2005
#1:  1                               16                               45
#2:  2                                8                               16
#3:  3                               10                               46
#4:  4                                6                               55
#5:  5                               12                                6
#6:  6                               84                               76
#7:  7                               61                               67
#8:  8                                9                               13
#   07.01.2005_08.01.2005
#1:                     2
#2:                     3
#3:                   734
#4:                     2
#5:                   469
#6:                    25
#7:                   837
#8:                    60

f2(dt,5)
#  Id 01.01.2005_02.01.2005_03.01.2005_04.01.2005_05.01.2005
#1:  1                                                     16
#2:  2                                                      9
#3:  3                                                     11
#4:  4                                                      7
#5:  5                                                     13
#6:  6                                                     84
#7:  7                                                     61
#8:  8                                                     12
#   06.01.2005_07.01.2005_08.01.2005
#1:                               47
#2:                               18
#3:                              779
#4:                               56
#5:                              474
#6:                              101
#7:                              904
#8:                               70
```

Using a slightly bigger dataset

```
set.seed(24)
dt <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(0:9, 5000*5000, replace=TRUE), 
     ncol=5000))
dt <- cbind(Id=1:5000, dt)
dim(dt)
#[1] 5000 5001
system.time(f2(dt, 4))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.269   0.022   2.291
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as David Arenburg's answer, but maybe a little more readable is to first take the group number by using the optimized `.GRP` operator from `data.table` and then taking the modulo of the step to obtain the index.

```
step <- 2
temp <- melt(dt, "Id")
temp[, group := .GRP + step-1L, variable]
temp[, indx := group %/% step]
dcast(temp, Id ~ indx, sum, value.var = "value")
```